# Get count of categories present in a column in separate columns in pivot table in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which looks like

[image: Sample table]

Now I want to get count of each category in State column in a separate column. Something like this.

[image: sample output]

I tried creating a pivot table, but the format is not what I want. My pivot looks something like.

[image: pivot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the layout you want, in the **PivotTable Field List** (usually on the right-hand side of Excel) you need to ensure that

- *Row Labels* contains Date
- *Column labels* contains State
- *Values* contains Count of State

so that you will get the following
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank You Dave, that was exactly what I needed.